# How to evaluate system of equations in Sympy?

Tags: sympy

I have the following system of equations

```
from sympy.abc import x,y,z
from sympy import solve, Eq

eqs = [Eq(x,y), Eq(y,z)]
result = solve(eqs, x)
```

now I want to be able to substitute a value for `z` and evaluate for `x`. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should include the two variables that you want to solve for after eqs and then proceed something as follows:

```
>>> result = solve(eqs, x, y)
>>> result[x].subs(z,42)
42
```